# transfer repository from bitbucket to github including open/close Pull requests

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket, pull-request

We are looking to move away from bitbucket to github but the only requirement is to keep all the history including open/close Pull requests and code reviews. I've been searching for a while and I'm not sure if thats even possible now. Surely there must be some super smart script which could handle all this.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/jeffwidman/bitbucket-issue-migration ?

Comment: @banyudu looks good, but it seems like the script can't transfer Pull Requests

Comment: Another repo: https://github.com/viperproject/bitbucket-issue-migration. I haven't used it before, so use it at your own risk.

Comment: Because issues and PRs and the like aren't part of Git, *Git* can't help you with your problem here. You'll need some software that uses the various APIs to obtain and transfer these non-Git databases from one hosting site to another. I'd suggest that you ask the hosting site you want to move *to* help you out here, since they might be interested in acquiring more customers as that's of benefit to them.